# Can i pass callback aync function in custom hook? Invalid hook call error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have:

A custom hook which is basicaly `useContext(MyContextName);`.

A component `Container` that takes children and wraps them in my context provider and passing there my function;

A component where I want to use my function. I'm destructuring it from custom hook and trying to call it in `useEffect`.

I can't include code but here is simplified vertion:

```
const MyContext = createContext({});

export const MyContainer = ({children}) => {
 const MyCoolFunction = async() =>{
  //do something
 }
 return (
  <MyContext.Provider value={{
      MyCoolFunction
    }}>
    {children}
  </MyContext.Provider>
 )
}

export const useMyHook = () => useContext(MyContext);
```

And in another component I do

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const {MyCoolFunction} = useMyHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    MyCoolFunction();
  }, []);

  return <something />;
}
```

And in a moment of calling `MyCoolFunction` I get "invalid hook call" error. But `MyCoolFunction` is not a hook, is it? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/new?fontsize=14 There is nothing wrong here. Problem is where you're calling `useMyHook` maybe?

Comment: @Dupocas, no i checked this. It doesnt work but for some other reasons. I just need to deal with this invalid hook call now to fix the rest of functionality

Comment: Post a sandbox with more details

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/can-i-pass-callback-aync-function-in-custom-hook-invalid-hook-call-error-e84nl), everything is working fine.

So here is my assumptions of why you are getting the error.

1 - Because you didn't mentioned where the error was, it can be an error from other component. Please provide where the error is happening.

2 - Are you sure you have `MyContainer` as a parent of `MyComponent`?

You need something like

```
return (
    <MyContainer> // parent of MyComponent
        ...
        <MyComponent />
    </MyContainer>
)
```

3 - Probably you are using a hook inside a function that isn't a react component.

In your question you have `MyComponent` that returns `<something />`. If that something, isn't a react component, you will get that error.

If none of these works, please provide the full error of "`invalid hook call`" for more detailed answers.

Comment: Good point. There is actually nothing wrong with how he's using context

Comment: well i guess error is somewhere else then. I checked your assumptions and it all seems correct.

Comment: Vencovsky, I checked your assumptions and it all seems correct.
1 - I don't actually know. Error message doenst tell me where error occurred. it just says react-dom.development.js:55. But i commentet all other components that may cause this and when i commenting call of MyCoolFunction i don't get this error. So i assume it's happening when i call MyCoolFunction in useEffect.
2 - MyContainer is in App component wrapping the router which have route for MyComponent. Should work, right?
3 - Nope, it's definitely a component

Comment: @Kruvorychka with the code you provided, I made a codesanbox and it's working perfect, probably there is something in or code that you didn't add in your question. Could you please create a codesandbox so I can debug it and solve the problem? Without your codesanbox, I won't be able to solve you problem

Answer (score 0):

Yep you all were right. This code works fine.

The problem was in "//do something" part in MyCoolFunction. I just called anoher hook in it and as the result i indirectly called myAnotherHook inside useEffect hook. Can't do that